# Namespaces in SAPUI5

Tags: namespaces, sapui5

Most of the time I encountered **sap.ui.demo.wt** as default namespace which I replaced with the name of my project(**Test**) and everything worked fine but lately I found this: **sap.ui.demo.navi**   when I was trying to implement navigation between Views...should I replace **sap.ui.demo.navi** with **Test** too or it should be something else? Please help me....and thank you for your time:)

```
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
  return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.nav.controller.Home", {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what's the set namespace for the resource root in the bootstrap in the index.html of the application. the data-sap-ui-resourceroots attribute in the bootstrap tells the sapui5 core where the resources in the defined namespace are located in the folder structure of the application relative to the index.html of the application.

i.e. in the code sample the resources of the application are located in the same folder as the index.html. because of the "./". when the application comes across the namespace "sap.ui.demo.wt" it starts to look for any resource in the folder of the index.html.

e.g. sap.ui.demo.wt.File means that the application looks for a File in the same folder as the index.html located.

e.g. sap.ui.demo.wt.view.File means that the application looks for a File in the folder view which is located one folder up from the index.html folder, i.e. ./view1/File. whereby again "./" the folder is where the index.html is located.

i.e. it's neccessary to replace "sap.ui.demo.nav" with "Test" if "sap.ui.demo.nav" is the namespace set in the bootstrap of the index.html. should e.g. "sap.ui.demo" be the namespace and "nav" just a folder in the folder structure of the applicaton then it's neccessary to replace "sap.ui.demo" without "nav".

from the structure of "sap.ui.demo.nav.controller.Home" i guess that "sap.ui.demo.nav" is the namespace, "controller" the controller folder in the application's folder structure and "Home" a controller. that would mean it's neccessary to replace "sap.ui.demo.nav" with "Test".

```
<script
  id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
  data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-preload="async"
  data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
    "sap.ui.demo.wt": "./" // tell here the app where the resources are located
  }'>
</script>
```